# How to remove the gutter from bootstrap carousel fluid when resized to mobile view?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, fluid, gutter

Hi all I have a basic carousel in bootstrap but when I resize to a mobile view suddenly a gutter appears on the left and the right? Does anyone know how to stop this from happening! Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You will ned to create a media query in your CSS (or several) in order to accomplish this.

Here is an example of how you would remove the padding & margin from the body at a "mobile" resolution.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however when i resize on my desktop browser the carousel still has a gutter?

Comment: as @Skelly pointed out, it looks like it is the `body` element that has the padding applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the body padding like this..

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    body {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

**Demo: http://bootply.com/59900**

Comment: Thank you so much this now works as I wanted. The caption box disappeared off the screen when enlarged but I changed its position to relative which seems to have done the trick. Thanks again

Comment: Testing the project, when I resize smaller the left and right controls do not resize smaller with the carousel the stay on the page as if it was full size? Any ideas at all please!